# Getting an error "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>" while finding region of interest of image in for loop

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, data-science

I am new to data science and trying to process my images. Below is the code for custom transformer that I am using to first convert image to gray scale then cropping and then resizing.
When these methods are performed on individual image, No such error is shown.
But when performed in For loop, getting type error.

```
class Preprocessing(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,dataset):
        # the constructor lets you specify which channel to select
        self.dataset=dataset
        X_data=[]
        #self.image_files=image_files

    def fit(self):
        # If the transformation depends on attributes of the training data
        # you can check those attributes here and store them on `self`.
        # However most transformers are "stateless" and immediately return self.
        return self

    def transform(self,image_files):
        # the transform method does the extraction
        X_data=[]
        for raw_image in image_files:
            image=cv2.imread(raw_image)
            image_gray=skimage.util.img_as_ubyte(skimage.color.rgb2grey(image[:,:,::-1]))
            row=self.dataset.index[self.dataset['Filename']==raw_image].tolist()
            row_data=self.dataset.iloc[row,:]
            Roi_X1=self.dataset.iloc[row,3]
            Roi_Y1=self.dataset.iloc[row,4]
            Roi_X2=self.dataset.iloc[row,5]
            Roi_Y2=self.dataset.iloc[row,6]
            region_of_interest=image_gray[int(Roi_X1):int(Roi_X2),int(Roi_Y1):int(Roi_Y2)]
            region_of_interest=skimage.util.img_as_ubyte(region_of_interest)
            image_resized = resize(region_of_interest, (64,64),anti_aliasing=True)
            image_resized=skimage.util.img_as_ubyte(image_resized)
            X_data.append(image_resized)


        return np.array(X_data, dtype='uint8')



dataset=pd.read_csv('Common.csv',sep=";")
image_files = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('E:\Mtech\Machine learning\Assessment\My_data-Copy\Work_folder\*.ppm')] 
preprocessing_pipeline = Pipeline([('Image Preprocessing', Preprocessing(dataset))])
my_processed_images = preprocessing_pipeline.transform(image_files)
```

The error is shown in line

```
---> 26  region_of_interest=image_gray[int(Roi_X1):int(Roi_X2),int(Roi_Y1):int(Roi_Y2)]
as 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self) --> 131  raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to " "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'
```

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Did you try to inspect/print relevant data just before that line to see what might be happening? Is `Roi_X?` supposed to be a Series or did you expect it to be a scalar? Or are you trying to convert all values in a Series to integers?

Comment: how many items contains your list: `row=self.dataset.index[self.dataset['Filename']==raw_image].tolist()` ? If it is more than one, it means that you are trying to convert to int Series which has many values and that is why you have this error. Which itself will mean that in your dataset you have duplicates.

Comment: @wwii I did print Roi_X1,Roi_X2,Roi_Y1,Roi_Y2 when performed these operations on individual images.Below is the output   

row index is [259]
row data is             Filename  Width  Height  Roi.X1  Roi.Y1  Roi.X2  Roi.Y2  ClassId
259  00019_00001.ppm     92      96       8       8      84      88       28
X1 is 259    8
Name: Roi.X1, dtype: int64
Y1 is 259    8
Name: Roi.Y1, dtype: int64
X2 is 259    84
Name: Roi.X2, dtype: int64
Y2 is 259    88
Name: Roi.Y2, dtype: int64. With this Roi measures, I am getting individual images cropped but when used in For it shows error

Comment: @RazmikMelikbekyan 'row' is a scalar, gives me index in dataset. where as in line row_data=self.dataset.iloc[row,:] , 'row_data' gives me complete row. Is 'Roi_X1=self.dataset.iloc[row,3]' not enough to get table element in variable?

Comment: @Namarta `row` is the list of integers, since you are calling `tolist` at the end.  If the number of integers in that list is 1 then your code will work, otherwise will throw an error. Check the length of `row` .